# Cannot calculate prime factors with a number with 12 digits in C

Tags: c, primes, prime-factoring

Im trying to learn alot more about C code by trying to do the examples on the Project Eular Page : http://projecteuler.net/problems
At the moment im trying to work out the highest prime factor from the number 600851475143.
Here is my code:

```
/* The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?*/
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long GetPrimeFactor(unsigned long long number)
{
    /* printf("The number you typed was %d\n", number);*/
    unsigned long long prime = 2;
    unsigned long long LargestPrime = 0;

    while (prime != 0)
    {
        if(number%prime == 0)
        {
            if(number == prime)
            {
                if(LargestPrime < prime)
                    LargestPrime = prime;

                printf("End of prime factors \nLargest Prime: %d\nEnding Number: %d\n", LargestPrime, number);
                break;
            }
            else if(LargestPrime < prime)
                LargestPrime = prime;

            //divide number by prime

            number = number/prime;
            printf("Prime: %d\n", prime);
        }

        else
        {
            //get new prime
            prime = nextPrimeNumber(prime);
        }
    }
}

unsigned long long nextPrimeNumber(unsigned long long input)
{
    unsigned long long nextPrimeNumber;

    while(input !=0)
    {
        if( input < 0)
        {
            printf("The number you have entered is negative\n");
        }
        else if (input > 0)
        {
            nextPrimeNumber = input + 1;

            if(nextPrimeNumber%2 == 0 && nextPrimeNumber != 2)
            {
                nextPrimeNumber += 1;
            }

            while(!isPrime(nextPrimeNumber))
            {
                nextPrimeNumber += 2;
            }

            return nextPrimeNumber;
        }
    }
}

int isPrime(int number)
{
    int i;
    int prime = 1; //true

    if(number == 2)
        prime = 0; //false

    if(number%2 == 0 || number <= 1)
        prime = 0;
    else
    {
        for(i=3; i<sqrt(number) && prime == 1; i+=2)
            if(number%i == 0)
                prime = 0;
    }

    return prime;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long number;

    printf("Enter a Number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    GetPrimeFactor(number);

    return 0;
}
```

This code works for the number 13195 which is in the example, but goes bad when i try the larger numbers and im not sure whats wrong.

output with large number 600851475143: prime: 3 prime: 29 prime: 5108231 etc.
this cant be correct because the number cannot be divisible by 3 anyway.

Cant work out whats going wrong so any help would be great

Comment: `600851475143` needs 40 bits to be represented in binary. Apparently your `int`s are 32 bits wide. Try with a larger type, eg: `long long unsigned`.

Comment: Your functions are defined in the wrong order. The compiler assumes they implicitly return `int`. This causes problems when trying to switch to a larger integer type. Define your functions before they are used.

Comment: 1) `int isPrime(int number)` should be `int isPrime(unsigned long long number)` 2) There are a couple places where you test for less than or equal.  Make sure you're not setting yourself up for failure in those spots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signed `ints` go up to 2147483647, `unsigned ints` go up to 4294967295, you could use `unsigned long long` which goes up to 18446744073709551615 and if you need something even bigger use an arbitrary-precision/bignum library like GnuMP ( http://gmplib.org/)

**Update to your edited question:**

The format specifier for scanf you use does not even read the whole `unsigned long long`, i read somewhere that you have to use `%llu`, however on my gcc this does not work, i have to use:

```
printf("Enter a Number: \n");
scanf("%I64d", &number);
printf("%I64d", number);  // <- make sure that this prints the number you 
                 // gave it before even calling GetPrimeFactor()
```

Comment: ok ive tried that by making my inital number variable an unsigned long long, but now its dividing by 181 which again cant happen but ill try and make all of the ints an unsigned long long

Comment: @spartan2417 you changed the question, so i edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for the help, i ended up defining my functions at the top of the page like @Complicated See bio said. and using unsigned long long. However i someone did suggest using uint64_t instead? would this still have the same effect?

Comment: @spartan2417 Try it out and please tell us.

Comment: They are both used for very Long numbers, but from the looks of it the only difference between putting "uint64_t" instead of "long long" is that uint64_t can hold 20 decimal digits instead of 19

Comment: @spartan2417 depends on the compiler which one works. if you write a library usable with multiple compilers you probably have to ifdef.

Answer (score 0):

have you changed scanf?

```
scanf("%L", &number)
```